# Correct pronunciation of "parietal lobe" from neuroanatomy

Tags: pronunciation, latin

When I studied neuroanatomy at university, my tutor (who later it turns out studied Latin in school), uses a different pronunciation than other neuroscientists. I prefer his pronunciation, but which one is technically correct, and for what reason?

My Tutor: pa-ri-ē-tal Everyone Else: pa-rī-e-tal

(please forgive my non-use of IPA, I can understand it but cannot write it accurately).

It comes from the Latin word, parietālis, which means "pertaining to a wall" (adj). That itself is derived from the Latin word, pariēs, meaning "wall" (noun).

The rule in Latin is to put the stress on the penult, unless the penult is a short syllable, which means we stress the antipenult instead. But as the word is shortened from parietālis, it makes sense that the stress should move a syllable to the left.

I appreciate that biological Latin has its own peculiar pronunciation style, but I'm not concerned about that: I want to know how it should be pronounced using Latinate pronunciation standards.

And with that, I've just thought I ought to post this on a Latin stack exchange. But we'll see what comes up, as it's still technically an English word

Comment: Seems like a dictionary could help.

Comment: The question was about reasoning through the arguments for each mode of pronunciation. Yes, I can read a dictionary, but there's no guarantee that the pronunciation in that is prescriptive rather than descriptive.

Comment: At what point does descriptive become prescriptive?  Some might say that being in the dictionary *makes* it prescriptive.

Comment: It's better to seem right than to be right. (Pronounce it like your peers do.)

Comment: All dictionaries are based on descriptive pronunciations. They are only prescriptive in the sense they tell you what is the more common or "accepted" pronunciation. And yes @TinfoilHat has the correct suggestion: pronounce it as your peers do. If there is divergence amongst your peers, then either would be acceptable.

Comment: Does your use of "ē" indicate /pʌ.raɪˈɪː.təl/ or /pʌ.raɪˈeɪ.təl/? (Note that there is an [IPA site](https://ipa.typeit.org/) and [helpful chart](http://www.antimoon.com/how/pronunc-soundsipa.htm) which I've found really useful.) It's a pity that Georgia on Windows doesn't make that look very pretty!

Comment: Latin puts the stress in [paries](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paries#Latin) on the first syllable, so when you add a syllable to it, shouldn't it make sense to move the stress one syllable to the right? Your reasoning isn't justified; you have to go back to the rule of where to put Latin stresses.

Comment: The way biologists and craniologists pronounce it  in the US is /pə'ɹayətəl/.

Comment: @PeterShor No, that this is not how Latin stress works. It does not just "automatically" move. It depends on the length of the vowel.

Comment: Nobody knows exactly how Latin was pronounced, and if you read a detailed text, you'll see the pronunciation changed over time (and there were probably regional variations, as there are with every other language). So "How was it pronounced in Latin?" is a complex question and is unlikely to give a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Jim commented, a dictionary will give the standard pronunciation. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parietal) has only one pronunciation for this word, and it's the one with stress on the "rī" syllable (your Everyone Else pronunciation).

If you're more comfortable comparing it with other English words of Latin origin, consider "varietal" (ultimately from Latin varietās 'variety'), which differs only in the initial consonant and also carries the stress on the "rī" syllable ([also in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/varietal)).